# Pure CSS way to keep image in ratio inside of display:table element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have simply no idea how to do so or if this is even possible with pure css?

This is my codebase …

```
<article class="layer">
      <img src="whatever.jpg" alt="image"/>
</article>

html, body, #content {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

article.layer {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

So I have articles with a class `layer` and they are set to `display:table` because I want them to be as high and wide as the current viewport.

Each of those articles has one `<img>` inside with different sizes.

I'm trying to create a kind of responsive webdesign!

The `<img>`s inside of the `article`s should be centered within its parent article and have a margin of like 30px. When resizing the browser-window the image should be scaled as well.

Here is a sample: http://jsbin.com/ugumuj/edit#preview

First off: How can I center the image inside of the display:table element? It should be centered vertically and horizontally.

Do I have to assign a width and height of the image or is it possible to kind of set it to 100% width within the browserwindow and the extra 30px margin.

I guess I probably need a lot of javascript to do so, right?

Regards, matt

Comment: you need a pure css solution then why the jquery tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to keeping the aspect ratio is to use `max-width` and `max-height` instead of `width` and `height`:

```
article.layer img {
   max-width: 80%;
   max-height: 80%;
}
```

For the centering, you can use an additional wrapper div, which is placed around the `<img>` element:

```
div.wrap {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

However, adding the 30px margin is not that easy. The percent relations apply to the screen size, so simply adding a margin will make it overflow the screen. The easiest way might be to add a full-screen div with `position: absolute`, which would act as a new reference for the percent measurements.

The complete code (without 30px margin) is here:
http://jsbin.com/ugumuj/10/edit

Comment: Instead of margins for images you can set padding to `.wrap`

Answer (score 2):

Its fairly simple for the vertical center. You need to the the `text-align: center` on the parent (article) element and use

```
margin: auto;
```

on the image itself. For the vertical center I guess you would need to have `margin-top` with a percentage value for instance.

Example: http://jsbin.com/ugumuj/11/edit

Comment: I was about to give closely this same answer, but I was gonna bet for margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;